# "Working on it" Image from SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, image, 2013

i was wondering if theres a fix for the missing image on the "Working on it"-Animation in SP2013 Preview
Google search didn't provisioned any fixes.. any ideas? Would like to solve that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing image is the progress16.gif in the 15 hive. Just replaced it with a gif from ajaxload.info and solved my issue..

Answer (score 4):

Previous post is correct, however maybe I can provide some more detail.

You need to put an image called progress16.gif here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\IMAGES

It doesn't matter where you get it from.  I took one of the other "wait" GIFs from the hive and just made a copy of it and renamed it.  You could also go here and make your own: http://ajaxload.info/.